# Lisp sockets for communication over the Internet

Tags: sockets, server, tcp, localhost, common-lisp

I'm trying to set up a game to run in Lisp on two computers on different internet connections. Thus, there is a need for TCP communication. I've tried [some](https://sinax.be/blog/lisp/programming-network-sockets-in-lisp.html) [toy](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/sockets.html) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796877/how-to-use-usocket-to-create-a-connection-common-lisp) with a server/client program and they work just fine on localhost, but no guides I found actually go on to use different machines. Trying that causes a "cannot connect" error. Is there some additional step for a distant connection versus localhost testing that I may be missing?

Comment: I'd use ping, netcat/socat, wireshark, etc. first to test if there is a network problem (DNS, NAT, firewalls). If that works fine, it should be easier to debug the client/server program ("cannot connect" is vague, if you have more details it can help)

Comment: Apologies for abandoning this question, we ended up using a different technology temporarily and because of holiday season there isn't much chance to coordinate for debugging. I'll get back to it for the sake of future searchers, but likely not before September.